# Does anyone know if blender 2.8 has a zbrush clip brush?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt

[image]

In [ZBrush](https://pixologic.com/) you are able to [clip a mesh](http://docs.pixologic.com/user-guide/3d-modeling/hard-surface/clip-brushes/) clean off instantly, no trimming that creates rough meshes everywhere. Is that possible in blender too?

Comment: Added your comment and a link to zbrush manual. Again, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Brockmann for helping.